# Reading n chars from stream to string

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stream

I need to read *n* `char`s from a binary file into a `string`. Currently, what I do is:

```
static string Read(istream &stream, uint32_t count)
{
    auto bytes = unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[count]);

    stream.read(bytes.get(), count);

    return string(bytes.get(), count);
}
```

I found the way I deal with the array of `char`s quite messy. If I used `new` and `delete[]` directly, it would make the code messy in another way (I would need to add a local variable for the result). And I'm trying to avoid `delete` as a general rule.

Is there a clear way to write this code? The fact that it uses twice as much memory as it needs is probably not a big deal, but fixing that would be nice too.

Comment: I think this is actually quite clean – albeit low-level – code. Nothing really wrong with it, and it’s probably more efficient than ruds’ implementation, although that’s arguably even cleaner.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: There is no need to be calling new here. Especially since the string object will deal with all that for you.

Comment: @Loki Ah true, I’d completely forgotten about C++11’s contiguity requirement.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not:

```
static string Read(istream &stream, uint32_t count)
{
    std::string result(count, ' ');
    stream.read(&result[0], count);

    return result;
}
```

Though not strictly C++03 compatible that is easily validated. One of the reasons the committee found it easy to add the new constraint in C++11 was that no implementation did not use contiguous memory (Random Access Iterators are a hint).

But a C++03 strict implementation would be:

```
static string Read(istream &stream, uint32_t count)
{
    std::vector<char> result(count);  // Because vector is guranteed to be contiguous in C++03
    stream.read(&result[0], count);

    return std::string(&result[0], &result[count]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly better.

Comment: Note that this requires C++11 in a non-obvious way (C++03 didn't require that &result[0] worked this way). Otherwise, LGTM.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may want to do `result.resize(stream.gcount());`, in case not all of `count` bytes could be read.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, it seems that you've got a `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace). ([No, really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

Here's a function that should meet your needs.

```
static std::string Read(std::istream &stream, std::string::size_type count)
{
    std::string out;
    out.reserve(count);
    std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator(stream), count, std::back_inserter(out));
    return out;
}
```

Comment: `uint32_t` should have an `std::` as well.

Comment: I don't have `using namespace std;` there. Instead, I have `using std::uint32_t;
using std::unique_ptr;
using std::string;
using std::istream;` there. It's kind of annoying, but I thought it would be better than writing `std::` everywhere.

Comment: @Jamal You're right. Actually, I've changed it to std::string::size_type, as that's the size class we're interested in.

Comment: @svick I think it's odd to read code with names from `std` but with no `std::` in front. Personal tastes vary, of course.

Comment: Is this going to insert the characters one by one? I worry that doing that would be too slow (the result might be one megabyte or so). (Of course, the proper way to find that out would be to measure it.)

Comment: @ruds: Ah, never heard of that (and seems better here, too).  Noted.

Comment: @svick: Do not quote me on this, but there _may_ be a `std::stringstream` alternative.  I don't know how (and if) it would work and whether or not it'll improve optimization.

Comment: @svick As you say, measurement is the key here. The istreambuf_iterator reads from the buffer underlying the istream, so I suspect this will be fine.

Comment: @Lstor: This is why I love C++11.  I just wish I could use more of it.

Comment: IMPORTANT. This example may not work properly for count = 0. The standard says an istreambuf_iterator may read the first character during construction. At least I observed such behavior with g++-4.8. To fix the code above, just skip copying if count == 0.